# React Router is not working fine with Exact and Switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

What I'm trying to do is on Edit page, I'm first searching for the item and then editing it.
So whenever I go to '/items/edit', it is also rendering ItemPage('/items/:id') page. Is there a way to work this out, or I've to change the link of Edit page to 'items-edit'.
 
I'm using 'react-router-dom' and my routes file looks like this.

```
// Relative imports
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

// Absolute imports
import YourReactComp from './YourReactComp.jsx';

const root = document.getElementById('root');

const MainPage= () => (
  <div>Main Page</div>
);


const const ItemPage= () => (
  <div>Item Page</div>
);

const EditPage= () => (
  <div>Edit Page</div>
);

const NoMatch = () => (
  <p>No Match</p>
);

const RoutedApp = () => (
  <BrowserRouter >
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/items/:id" component={ItemPage} />
      <Route exact path="/items/edit" component={EditPage} />          
      <Route path="/yourReactComp" component={YourReactComp} />        
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />          
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(<RoutedApp />, root);
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the order of these two routes? Route with parameter is more generic than the one with edit.

Comment: @tswistak OP seems to be saying that both the routes are rendering at once. Which shouldnt be happening.

Comment: @yash can you use http://codesandbox.io/ to create a sample. Since your code seems to be completely correct. Only either of `ItemPage` and `EditPage` should be rendered at once and not both.

Comment: sure, I'll make a sandbox.

Comment: yes, I've tried to change the order and also tried to change the exact prop.

Comment: this is sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/link-router-dom-xjz1g.

Comment: The sanbox isn't reflecting the issue exactly. Actually we're rewriting an app. And from nginx server we're reloading the page. So on reload both the pages will render if I try to go to '/items/edit', but 'items/:id' is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your switch is matching the route param first

```
      <Route exact path="/items/:id" component={ItemPage} />
      <Route exact path="/items/edit" component={EditPage} />
```

This is the same path i.e. `edit` considered is a parameter. The below should work.

```
    <Route exact path="/items/edit" component={EditPage} />
    <Route exact path="/items/:id" component={ItemPage} />
```

Test with paths `http://.../items/12`, `http://.../items/edit`

Comment: Already tried this. Not working on reloads. ie if I reload page on book/edit,  both comps will render.

Comment: I see in a comment above you mention nginx, maybe the issue is there? In your code sample `book/edit` is an undefined route, it will display NoMatch

Comment: No, 'items/edit' will work fine if I comment out 'items/:id' route. Yes maybe, in the nginx their is some issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `/items/edit` assumes `edit` as the `:id`. You need to change the routes like this:

```
<Route exact path="/items/:id" component={ItemPage} />
<Route exact path="/items/:id/edit" component={EditPage} />
```

So, You can add other routes like this beautifully. I've provided a sandbox example for you.
[Click to view Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-night-ukis9?file=/src/index.js:585-705)

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

P.S: if you insist not to provide `id` for edit page, You need to change your routes completely. For example like this:

```
<Route exact path="/item/:id" component={ItemPage} />
<Route exact path="/items/edit" component={EditPage} />
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. But I don't want to change the links. But if i did not find any solution, I've to change the link. :|
Also the first solution you provided, will not work for me. As on 'book/edit' I'm searching for the title and doing the update there.

Comment: @YashJaiswal You have to change the routes because there isn't other solutions. Sandbox example is working fine. I've included some screenshots in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just type const two times on the item page. It is working fine on my hand. And you just have to change the position of the below routes

```
   <Route exact  path="/items/edit" component={EditPage} />      
      <Route exact path="/items/:id" component={ItemPage} />



    // Relative imports
        import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
        
        // Absolute imports
        import YourReactComp from './YourReactComp.jsx';
        
        const root = document.getElementById('root');
        
        const MainPage= () => (
          <div>Main Page</div>
        );
        
        
        const  ItemPage= () => (
          <div>Item Page</div>
        );
        
        const EditPage= () => (
          <div>Edit Page</div>
        );
        
        const NoMatch = () => (
          <p>No Match</p>
        );
        
        const RoutedApp = () => (
           <BrowserRouter >
    <Switch>
      <Route exact  path="/items/edit" component={EditPage} />      
      <Route exact path="/items/:id" component={ItemPage} />
      <Route path="/yourReactComp" component={YourReactComp} />        
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />          
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
        );
        
        ReactDOM.render(<RoutedApp />, root);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: No. It is not working. Do  a reload on 'items/edit', both comp will rerender.

Comment: Okay. So I guess the issue is in server-side rendering, for me. Thanks for the help!